Forward+ quality texture color depth on Mobile?
I'm using a .hdr file as my Sky background and it looks great on Forward+. But I'd prefer to stay on Mobile, because of performance. However, Mobile causes my .hdr Sky background to look poor and I was wondering if there is any way to have Mobile less radically compressing my Sky background? Mobile especially seems to take away a lot of color depth.
I've already tried to disable compression (and also randomly fiddled around with some of the other properties but I'm honestly a bit overwhelmed) but nothing works – apart activating Forward+.
